# .find at element.find() throws "undefined is not a function" - AngularJS, File upload

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, model-view-controller, base64

I am trying to implement image upload and save to database feature on my practice project. I have created a dialog modal and 3 different directives for modal elements: one for text input, second for select (drop down) and third for file uploads. I am having trouble with the file upload because browser is reporting "undefined is not a function" error on .find at var input = element.find("input")[0];

[image: .find error]

I have this AngularJS directive that looks like this.

```
collectionsApp.directive('formFileUpload', [function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            name: '@',
            fileread: '='
        },
        templateUrl: '/directives/formFileUpload.html',
        link: function(scope, attrs, element) {
            var input = element.find("input")[0];
            input.addEventListener("change", function(changeEvent){
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (loadEvent) {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        scope.fileread = loadEvent.target.result;
                    });
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(changeEvent.target.files[0]);
            })

        }
    }
}]);
```

And I have this formFileUpload.html to replace directive:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputFile" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{name}}</label>
    <div class='col-sm-3'>
        <input type="file">
    </div>
</div>
```

And when I add directive to modal body I add it like this:

```
<form-file-upload name="Book Cover Image" fileread="file"></form-file-upload>
```

Now, keep in mind that I intend to convert this image with base64, store it as a property of an object and send it to db.

Comment: `.find` is not a method available on DOM nodes, so it's `undefined`. I think you meant, `.getElementsByTagName()` or maybe `querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: I still get the same error message even if I use element.getElementsByTagName('input') or querySelectorAll('input') - undefined is not a funct...

Comment: Add a `console.log(element)` to make sure that it's what you think it is - an answer below suggests that you've gotten the parameter order wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that you have the order of passed parameters to your link function wrong.

It should be:

```
link : function(scope, element, attrs)
```

not:

```
link : function(scope, attrs, element)
```